# UIView update animations limit count

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, uiviewanimation

I got this error:

> too many update animations on one view - limit is 31 in flight at a
>   time

When executing `[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];`

Now I'm trying to limit the number of that method being called.

The question is, how can I know what is the **limit count** for the update animations count? In the above error, the limit is **31**.

Should I hardcode the value?

EDIT:

```
[cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[tempDictionary objectForKey:@"image"] objectForKey:@"url"]]] placeholderImage:placeholderImage options:SDWebImageRetryFailed completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType) {
    if (!image)
        [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
}];
```

basically the code above requests for an image to be set to an `UIImageView`. If the request failed (no image received), it tells the `UITableView` to reload the cell, thus requesting the image once more.

Comment: I think you missunderstoon how to use reaload function. Can you paste code where you call this function?

Comment: @OscarYuandinata, have you resolved this issue? I just found the same error in UICollectionView.

Comment: @Itachi, I used this code in cellForRow function. I resolve this problem by not calling it as setImageWithURL will get called everytime the cell comes into view

Comment: @OscarYuandinata then is that related with web request? What if all the images is loaded from local bundle, how did you update/set the image for cell finally?